# facebook test user like

Tags: facebook, facebook-test-users

I am now using Facebook API.  The aim is to determine that he is not a fan of the Facebook fan page

So I want to ask Facebook to help me open the delegated authority
I need to open a test account good they do audit

But I found that when I use the test account
And have no way to praise, because there is no press Like button appears

Because I need to obtain a judgment that is to praise

I do not know do not do it, or are there any alternative options?

I hope you can help me doubts

Comment: Like gating is not allowed. So why do you need if a user liked your page?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

— My Test users are friends with each other
— One test user posts a status update
— I log in as the other test user. The post appears on my timeline, but I have only a "share" button, NO LIKE BUTTON.